# Array push yields unexpected array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Simple question I hope (not sure what I am missing);

How can I push items to a basic and not an indexed array?

When doing this:

```
var shops = [];     
angular.forEach(data, function(value, index) { //loop over data
    shops.push(value.SHOP_CODE);
});
```

[image]

Comment: It is the same thing

Comment: Those are the same thing. Note you might have logged that array before it was filled (which is why you got `Array[0]` as it had no length at the time. But when you went to go look at it in the console it had filled. The initial line for a logged array does not update when the array updates

Comment: I think you're correct. Im returning a promise and it's likely not being returned fast enough. Racking my brain - Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript arrays always use numbered indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Patrick Evans and @SLePort, I realized I needed to wait for the promise. This works:

```
.$promise.then(function(data) {
   $scope.workOrder = data;
       angular.forEach(data, function(value, index) { //loop over aircraft data
                        shops.push(value.SHOP_CODE);
                });
           shops.sort();
           console.log(shops);
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are logging the shops array to console, the array is probably empty and hence it says Array[0].

The contents of the array are evaluated again when you click the dropdown arrow beside Array[0]. So at the time of your click on the dropdown the array is not empty and hence showing 4 elements.

If the array were not empty at the point where you do console.log(shops), then you would get the result you are looking for.

I suggest you add a breakpoint at the statement console.log(shops) and check the contents of the array.

Comment: Thank you @shriharska. Actually it was that I wasn't waiting for the promise to return and the array wasn't filling completely.